# Batch script to assign AWK path

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk

so I currently have the following batch script called delim.bat:

```
@echo off 
awk -f file1.awk Main.dat
```

And I would like to run it from a stored procedure as follows:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"\\WindowsSQL034\Source\delim.bat"'
```

However, since gawk is not pointed to a path in windows control panel, it will give me an error saying

> 'awk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I currently have gawk installed in another network's drive (\Wind34\batch) So I am wondering if there is a line I could add to my delim.bat file to be able to run that file from SQL without having troubles?

**Note:** I don't have access to point it from the SQL's server in Control Panel - System - Advanced Tab - Path like I can do on my own machine.

Or would you have another solution or alternative to run it? Like maybe a button I can on an intranet (html / classic asp-javascript) page.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `awk` by `\Wind34\batch\gawk` or by its Windows path found by:

```
where awk
```